# Taking tcpdump of data transmitting through tunnel

Tags: vpn, linux-networking, tcpdump, tunnel, packet-sniffer

I have a service provider, who provides connection to his SMPP server only through a VPN. We setup a tunnel to connect to his VPN.

Now there are some issues with the connectivity and I need to check the tcpdump. But I am not able to do so.

I couldn't find any proper example or documentation to do so.(though there were lots of example of tcpdump for direct dst host and port)

Can anyone please help me on this? or can at least tell, where I should be looking at? (I also tried to take a tcpdump without any param, fetching all distinct dst and src IPs and taking individual dump, but that too went in vein)

Comment: Could you share details on this VPN solution?

Comment: I am not sure about the VPN details, as it was set up by the previous system-admin. And I am not a system admin, I only know that it is IPSec tunnel

Comment: You would need to capture the traffic from inside the tunnel.  There may be an internal interface on the vpn device that could be spanned/mirrored or otherwise tapped.

Comment: What issues you have? What VPN you use?